# Need help solving simple error In C while writing calculating program

Tags: c

So I'm new to programming, I learned a bit of C and figured I would write a program that calculates grade letters from percents. I'm not sure What I did wrong. I'm sure you guys can figure this out pretty easily, I'ts probably something simple and dumb I'm missing. It says the problem occurs on line 15. I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Open to any feedback too, thank you.

```
int main() {

   char grade[] = {
     'A',
     'A-',
     'B+',
     'B',
     'B-',
     'C+',
     'C',
     'C-',
     'D+',
     'D',
     'D-',
     'F'
   };
   double percent;
   
   char result;
   
   printf("Enter Grade Percentage: ");
   scanf("%f", & percent);
   
   if (percent >= 93) {
     result = grade[0];
   } else if (percent = 90, 91, 92) {
     result = grade[1];
   } else(percent = 87, 88, 89) {
     result = grade[2];
   } else(percent = 83, 84, 85, 86) {
     result = grade[3];
   } else(percent = 80, 81, 82) {
     result = grade[4];
   } else(percent = 77, 78, 79) {
     result = grade[5];
   } else(percent = 73, 74, 75, 76) {
     result = grade[6];
   } else(percent = 70, 71, 72) {
     result = grade[7];
   } else(percent = 67, 68, 69) {
     result = grade[8];
   } else(percent = 63, 64, 65, 66) {
     result = grade[9];
   } else(percent = 60, 61, 62) {
     result = grade[10];
   } else(percent < 60) {
     result = grade[11];
   }
   printf("Grade %s", result);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I can see many problems, but for the sake of _reporting_ an issue or asking a question, I want to point out that you have not provided useful detail.  _What_ says there's a problem?  The compiler?  What is the message?  Which line is line 15?

Comment: You are using assigning operator "=" instead of equal to "==". Moreover you can only compare two items. Like `percentage == 88`. If you want to check for a range you have to do `percentage <= 92 && percentage >= 90`. Also you are using else statement wrong.

Comment: Please take a short moment to read through [this](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/what-is-difference-between-assignment-and-equalto-operator.aspx) (That is the first link i found googling for difference between = and ==)

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, you're using malformed character literals when declaring a `char` array:

```
char grade [] = {'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F'};
```

I think you intended to have an array of *strings*.  Something like `A-` is *two* characters.  You cannot define a character literal with more than one character.  Instead, you probably want an array of strings:

```
const char *grade [] = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"};
```

Now, you have a bunch of issues with lines like this:

```
else if (percent = 90, 91, 92)
```

This is actually performing an assignment (`percent = 90`) and then comparing whether `92` is non-zero, which it is.  What you obviously intended was:

```
else if (percent >= 90 && percent <= 92)
```

However, you had already compared `if (percent >= 93)` just before this `else if`, and so `percent <= 92` is redundant but only IF `percent is an integer`.  It's actually not, but more on that later.

So why not chain like this:

```
const char *result = NULL;
if (percent >= 93)
    grade = grade[0];
else if (percent >= 90)
    grade = grade[1];
else if (percent >= 87)
    grade = grade[2];
```

And so on...

Now, this actually works with fractional scores.  If you had entered `92.5`, your old approach of specified ranges would not have worked (unless you used `&& percent < 93` instead of `&& percent <= 92`).

But why repeat so much code?

```
const char *grade [] = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"};
int threshold[] = { 93, 90, 87, 83, 80, 77, 73, 70, 67, 63, 60, 0 };

const char *result = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < 12 && !result; i++) {
    if (percent >= threshold[i])
        result = grade[i];
}
```

Finally, consider using `int` as the type of your percentages if they will *never* be fractional.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in the program.

The most important one (note the use of `==` to denote comparison and `||` to denote a logical or),

```
if (percent = 90, 91, 92)
```

should be

```
if (percent == 90 ||
    percent == 91 ||
    percent == 92) {
  ...
}
```

and several of the else directives are missing the `if` clause, i.e., `else if (...) {`.

When you want to use strings, you should use `"` and not `'`.  Because a string is a pointer to characters in C, an array of strings should be an array of pointers to characters (note the `*` in my correction).  Similarly, the result variable should be a character pointer. Hence,

```
char grade[] = {'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-' ...
double percent;
char *result;
```

should be

```
char *grade[] = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-" ...
double percent;
char *result;
```

Next, the `%f` formatting parameter passed to `scanf` should be `%lf` because you would like to read a double and not a float (double is a double precision floating point number).

Answer (score 0):

this `else (percent = 63, 64, 65,66){` does not exist in C.

comparison is done with `==` : `percent == 63`
multiple comparison are done by using or operator : `||`

so : `else (percent == 63 || percent == 64 || ...){`

event better, you can check a range with `>`, `>=`...: `else (63 <= percent && percent <= 66) {`

Comment: That does "exist" (ie is syntactically valid) in C, but it doesn't at all mean what the OP hoped it means.

Comment: yes, comma operator exists, I just "adapted' my answer to OP skill level